# Annotation Processor in Eclipse with Ant process() not running

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javac, annotation-processing

this is a last resort question. I have searched all over the internet for what could possibly be wrong, but nothing seems to work. I have created a custom annotation that should generate a resource file, the classes are as follows:

```
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(CLASS)
@Repeatable(Schedules.class)
public @interface Scheduled {

    /**
     * Specifies one or more minutes with in an hour. 
     */
    int[] minute() default {};
    
    /**
     * Specifies one or more hours within a day.
     */
    int[] hour() default {};
    
    /**
     * Specifies one or more days in a month
     */
    int[] date() default {};
    /**
     * Specifies one or more months within a year.
     */
    int[] month() default {};
    
    /**
     * Specifies one or more days within a week.
     */
    int[] dayOfWeek() default {};

}
```

and

```
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(CLASS)
public @interface Schedules {

    Scheduled[] value();
}
```

The annotation processor is structured as follows:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"files.application.Scheduled"})
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class ScheduledProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    
    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment env) {
        super.init(env);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
       ...
    }
    
    public void buildFile(ArrayList<String> scheduledList) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Test class for the annotation:

```
public class AnnotationTest {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    
    @Scheduled
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
    
    @Scheduled(month= {7,8})
    @Scheduled(date= {5,6})
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

We use ANT tasks to accomplish many tasks with the code, one being `compile`.

```
    <target name="-compile" depends="-pre-compile,-classpath-compile">
        <mkdir dir="${build.bin}"/>
        <javac
            destdir="${build.bin}" 
            encoding="UTF-8"
            includeAntRuntime="false" 
            debug="true" 
            debuglevel="${build.javac.debuglevel}"
            source="${build.javac.source}"
            target="${build.javac.target}"
        >
            <src path="${build.source}" />
            <src path="${build.gen}" />
            <classpath refid="classpath.compile" />
            
            <compilerarg line="-processor files.application.ScheduledProcessor"/>
            <compilerarg line="-s ${build.source}" />
        </javac>
```

My current project structure is:

```
core
    src
        annotsProject
                 Scheduled.java
                 Schedules.java
                 ScheduledProcessor.java
                 AnnotationTest.java
        META-INF
             services
                  javax.annotation.processing.Processor
    anttasks.xml
```

When I run the compile ANT task, the `init(ProcessingEvironment env)` is successfully called, but `process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv)` never gets called. I have tried creating a .jar file of the processor and the META-INF folder and adding it to the project build path, but no go. I have tried using `javac` from the command line, and still nothing. Maybe I am misunderstanding when the `process()` method should be called or maybe my folder structure is wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after posting the question. I moved `AnnotationTest.java` to its own project, `testProj`, and added a dependency for `testProj` to `core`'s ivy.xml that we use. I compiled `core`, which finished successfully, but did not display any information about the annotation processor. I then built its artifacts with a separate `ANT` command. Then I compiled `testProj`, it did display my `printMessage()`, that I have in my `process()`, in the annotation processor. I checked the output location for the file I wanted created, and it was there! I think that `.jar` method of using the annotation processor was the right direction, but I might have put it in the wrong location for how our projects are set up. The artifacts `ANT` command we use, built the `.jar` for me and put it in the proper location so that `testProj` would see it. Posting my answer in case it helps anyone.